# StaleDataException with dialog

Tags: android, staledataexception

I am trying to show a dialog with a listview with names from my database but I keep getting a `StaleDataException`. I know that usually means I am trying to use data from a closed cursor but the cursor does not close until I get all the data so I dont understand why I am getting this

```
d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
d.setTitle("Select Bowler");

ListView lv = (ListView)d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list);
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    BowlersDB.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] {
        BowlersDB.ID, BowlersDB.FIRST_NAME, BowlersDB.LAST_NAME
    },
    null,
    null,
    BowlersDB.LAST_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC"
);

if (c.moveToFirst() && c != null) {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.names_listview,
        c,
        new String[] {
            BowlersDB.FIRST_NAME, BowlersDB.LAST_NAME
        },
        new int[] {
            R.id.bListTextView, R.id.bListTextView2
        },
        0
    );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            bowlerClickedID = id;
            updateName(id);
        }
    });
    d.show();
}
c.close();
```

error

```
android.database.StaleDataException: 
   Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow. 
   Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.

   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
   at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150)
   at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
   ...
```

EDIT:
If I comment out the `c.close()` line it works fine but I cant just leave the cursor open though so what do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot close the cursor until CursorAdapter is no longer needed. So you can close it in onDestroy() method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();

 ListView lv = (ListView) d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list);
 ((CursorAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).getCursor().close();
 database.close();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You're getting your error because you're closing the `Cursor` while the `SimpleCursorAdapter` you create might still be trying to access data from it.

If you want to use a `CursorLoader`, as you should be doing.

1. Keep a reference to your adapter as an instance variable
2. Create your simple cursor adapter with a reference to null for the cursor
3. Have your class implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`
4. Actually create the `CursorLoader` in the `onCreateLoader`
5. In `onLoadFinished()`, swap the cursors with `adapter.swapCursor(cursor)`
6. In `onLoaderReset()`, swap the cursor with a `null` cursor as adapter.swapCursor(null)`

You should also end up putting your data in a ContentProvider - it's not that bad!

Comment: Why `swapCursor` ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor) ) rather than `changeCursor` ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor) ) ?

Answer (score 0):

I used to rely on `startManagingCursor` method to leave the hassle of opening and closing `Cursors` to the system. Now that it is deprecated (it still works but I would not recommend using it), consider using the `CursorLoader` class with `LoaderManager` and leave it to the system to handle the Cursor closing.